# How to design unit tests for a web service client?

Tags: python, web-services, unit-testing

I am creating a microblog (Twitter and Status.Net) library for Python, and wish to create unit tests for it. I'm not really sure of the best way of doing this.

Obviously the data returned from the service will be different each time - there will be new posts etc. Also, I cannot force Twitter to fail whale to test for that.

With Status.Net, I could conceivable set up a private server to use for testing but it still seems like there must be a better way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard way is to mock the service.  http://code.google.com/p/pymox/ makes that pretty easy.

Comment: To elaborate a bit, I usually capture actual response messages from remote services. I then use those as test fixtures to make sure that my code can understand the responses.